# Microsoft chart control failing to set background transparent

Tags: c#, mschart

I have a microsoft pie chart control. I am setting the background transparent, but it is staying white. As you can see I've set the BackColor and PageColor properties of the BorderSkin. I've also set the BackColor of the ChartArea as well. Here's some code.

```
Chart chart = new Chart
            {
                Width = 190,
                Height = 159,
                RenderType = RenderType.BinaryStreaming,
                AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.Graphics,
                TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.Normal
            };

            // turn on transparency
            chart.BorderSkin.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            chart.BorderSkin.PageColor = Color.Transparent;
            chart.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;

            chart.ChartAreas.Add("");

            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1; // setting this to 1 forces all items to show
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = true;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleFont = xLabelFont;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;

            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TitleFont = yLabelFont;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.IsStaggered = false; // staggers axis label
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Horizontal;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.All;

            chart.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            chart.Series.Add("");
            chart.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
            //chart.Series[0]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled"; // disable labels
            chart.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true; // *** super important to be able to manually set labels show point labels for value ***

            chart.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
```

Comment: More info - http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2010/10/microsoft-chart-35-simple-charts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see this line:

```
chart.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Comment: Great thanks. For other's I also had to disable the line chart.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;

Answer (score 1):

Colors of chart, chart's area(s), legends, etc... are set separately.
And remember add:

```
chart.TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.SystemDefault;
```

when you set the background of the chart to transparent, or you will get terrible low quality fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I needed these two lines:

```
chart.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
chart.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```